# Chrome profiler - Why do functions sometimes stop for a little time?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, profiling, google-chrome-devtools, profiler

Here is a picture of my web execution captured by Chrome Performance Devtools:

[image]

I notice that functions will be stopped many times during execution, when my web functions are stopped Chrome executes some RegExp operations (as shown in the picture). I don't understand what this is, and why it happens. Please help explain, thanks.

**Update:** here is a function which is also executed in the same manner:

[image]

Comment: Are you using some templating library (Polymer, Meteor, Angular, etc) that uses double-curly syntax and manipulating attributes or HTML? The RegExp appears to be looking for databindings.

Comment: Yes, I am using Backbone/Marionette with [soma template](http://soundstep.github.io/soma-template/#data-html) as custom template

Comment: Well from a glance it looks like that regex has something to do with templating - searching for {{...}}

Answer (score 5):

#### What you describe

The way you describe the problem it sounds like you think the JavaScript virtual machine is putting the functions on hold (stopping them) while they are executing (i.e. before they return) to do something else and then resumes the functions.

The image you are showing does not suggest that at all to me.

#### What I'm seeing

The VM executes:

- `callback`, which calls
- some function whose name is hidden by a tooltip, which calls:
- `fireWith`, which calls:
- `fire`, which calls:
- etc...

Then the deepest function returns, and the one that called it returns, and so on and so forth until `fire` returns, `fireWith` returns, the function whose name we cannot read returns, and `callback` returns.

Then the VM runs a RegExp function, and it calls a function named `callback` again, and the whole thing starts anew. **In other words, the second column with `callback` and the rest is a new invocation of the functions.** The functions are not "stop[ping] for a little time": they are called multiple times.

I see this all the time in libraries that respond to events. They typically will loop over event handlers to call them. Given a complex enough library, there'a fair amount of glue code that may sit between the loop that calls the handlers and your custom code so there's a lot of repetitive calls that show up in profiling.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You seem to be right, but not entirely though. I put a `console.log('callback')` command inside `callback` function to check how many times it is called. I found out that it is really called many times, but still less than the times it appears on the profiler. There is also another function (not a callback) gets call directly, this function only prints to console once but appears many times in profiler. What do you think?

Comment: Are the counts of `callbacks` the same every time you run it? Not sure about this "other function" can you please give more information on that also?

Comment: The counts of `callback` are not the same on profiler, but the numbers of messages on console are the same. The other function is a normal function got called directly after the page first load. I will include a picture of it on profiler in the question

Comment: I'm not sure you are right. I added a console log and saw that a function was invoked only once, but in the performance timeline I saw two bars separated by a gap for that function. Maybe the author of the question is right and the VM interrupts execution sometimes.Or maybe this is an artifact of a sampling profiler.